# Can I use the phrase "at its best" to refer to a party?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Can I use these idioms to convey for example:

> We left the party at its best (at the party's peak; while the party was reaching its peak; while the party was going really well)

Comment: when the party was in **full swing**.

Comment: That works, but @Lambie has a better construction, If you are asking about "at its best" in general, please [edit] the question to show us several more ways you might want to use it.

Comment: No, using "at its best" does not work in reference to parties. The phrase is used to refer to things of much longer duration, like the rule of a king, a business, a nation, and so forth. It also implies that there are periods either before or after when X was **not** at its best.

Comment: I think the negative "not at its best" is much more common than the positive "at its best".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it works.

A party starts off as a beginning, which is not so interesting. In the middle, it gets better, at which time you would call it "at its best." So, leaving at the party's best would mean leaving in the middle.